# Why drag and drop not working html5?

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to drag a file into the body of my page and pop an alert box. Why is the event not getting caught?

In my script tags:

```
    jQuery.event.props.push('dataTransfer');
    $("body").on('drop', function(event) {
      alert("Drop");
      event.preventDefault();
       var files = event.dataTransfer.files;

    });

$("body").on("dragover", function(event) {
  return false;
});
```

Jquery 2.x is included and running on chrome browser. WHen I drag an image from my explorer window into the browser window, it just replaces the URL with the location of my image and shows the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include your event within `$(document).ready(...`:

```
$(function(){
    jQuery.event.props.push('dataTransfer');
    $("body").on('drop', function(event) {
      alert("Drop");
      event.preventDefault();
       var files = event.dataTransfer.files;

    });

    $("body").on("dragover", function(event) {
      return false;
    }); 
});
```